# SQL Parameters type from string

Tags: vb.net

I need to set up the parameter type from my predefined type

Tried with

```
  For Each row3 In _TypeList
      Dim myType As SqlDbType
      myType = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(SqlDbType), row3), SqlDbType)
      _cmd.Parameters.Add("@" & parName, SqlDbType.?? ).Value = "FOO"
  Next
```

Is there any way i can set my own `SqlDbType.row3` ?

Comment: Various ideas: firstly when you have a doubt regarding the possible arguments which a given .NET function take, you should do a quick check yourself before asking here (you don't need even to do any research; just use the marvellous Visual Studio intuitive helps which allow to easily skim through all the possible overloads of the given method); in this case, all the overloads of Parameters.Add include the `SqlDbType` enumeration (i.e., not `Type` outside the ones in this list is possible). Another good idea when finding a problem is thinking about the exact reason of the behaviour...

Comment: ... the whole point of a parameterised query is precisely to restrict the type of contents which the given parameter my accept (you know... to avoid things like SQL injection).  That's why allowing to freely define these contents would seem against the whole purpose of the given functionality. Bear in mind that the elements of a given enum are not the same than the type of the enum, which is basically enum; that is what you want to do (as I undertand it: making sure that the given contents match one of the elements in the enum) has nothing to do with types. One thing is number vs. string...

Comment: @varocarbas you dont get it. I read those types from `SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'XXX'` after that i want to dynamically create the sql parameters which will read this type from here

Comment: ... (for example: the types int vs. string) and a different thing are the contents of a variable of any type; for example: including only 1s or strings which contain the letter "a". Parameterised queries are not meant to deal with contents, but with the types (i.e., making sure that when a number is expected, a number will be used). I hope that your ideas are now a bit clearer.